# Не выводит значение coockie на основной странице

Tags: php, cookie

Помогите пожалуйста! Есть 2 файла: 1. index.php (главный) 2. auth.php.
В auth.php создал cookie для авторизации, когда проверяю на наличие кука в файле index.php результат проверки только "нет кука". Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что если кук есть выводился определенный контент, а когда его нет или истекло время кука то показывались формы авторизации. Все данные прередаются методом ajax. Спасибо!

index.php:

```
<?php
    include "php/header.php";
?>
<main>
    <?php 
    if(!empty($_COOKIE["user"])) {
        echo 'кук юзер есть';
    }else{
        echo 'кук юзер нет';
    }
    ?>
        <section class="form">
        <div class="form__container">
            <ul class="form__btn_container">
                <li id="form_vchod" data-atr="vchod" class="form_btn_link_actve">Вход</li>
                <li id="form_reg" data-atr="register">Регистрация</li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form__vchod form__start form__start_active">
                <h2 class="form__title">ВХОД</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Логин*" class="form__start_input form_start_login">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль*" class="form__start_input form_start_password">
                <div class="error dn"></div>
                <div class="send_server dn"></div>
                <button class="form__start_input form__start_vchod_input">ВОЙТИ</button>
            </form>
            <form class="form__register form__start">
                <h2 class="form__title">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Логин*" class="form__start_input form_start_register_login">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль*" class="form__start_input form_start_register_password">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ключ*" class="form__start_input form_start_register_key">
                <div class="error dn"></div>
                <div class="send_server dn"></div>
                <button class="form__start_input form__start_resister_input">ЗАРЕГЕСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>


<?php
    include "php/footer.php";
?>
```

auth.php:

```
<?php

    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $passwor = filter_var(trim($_POST['passwordss']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $passwor = md5($passwor."asjdhkajshd7787hakjsndlkasmdl");

    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'crm_jama');
    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$passwor'");
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(empty($user) or count($user) == 0) {
        echo 'Такой пользователь не найден';
    }
    if(is_array($user)) {
        setcookie("user", $user['name'], time() + 4, "/");
    }
    

    
    $mysql->close();
```

Comment: Чем Вас сессии не устраивают? Куки для другого нужны